# phpDocumentor using extremely low version of phpDocumentor Reflection Docblock dependency issue

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdocumentor2

I'm trying to install the `dev-master` version of `phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor` however when I execute:

```
composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master
```

I get the following issues:

```
Problem 1
- phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0a2, 2.0.0a3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.0, 2.0.0a1, 2.0.0a2, 2.0.0a3, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor dev-master -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[dev-master].
```

My composer configurations are:

```
"minimum-stability" : "dev",
"prefer-stable" : false,
"require":{
  "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock" : "4.3.0",
}
```

The issue I'm having is that my current `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock` version is `4.3.0`.

When I try to execute this:

```
php composer.phar require phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock:~2.0
```

I then get an issue as:

```
Problem 1
- felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc v3.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ^4.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc v3.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ^4.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc v3.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ^4.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc v3.0.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ^4.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.2.0, 4.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc (locked at v3.0.1) -> satisfiable by felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc[v3.0.1].
```

I'm not quite sure how to resolve this dependency issue. **Should I just download the sourcecode instead?**

Answer (score 0):

If `felixfbecker/advanced-json-rpc` requires a version later than 4.0, you cannot install version 2.x. According to https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1834, you should install phpDocumentor from the provided phar to avoid version conflicts.

After all, it looks like this is not a really solid framework. They promised an update a year ago and still depend on a version that is two years old...